# How to use different file name for same file while using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I can use 
file_get_contents("https://example.com/file.txt?some");
And I want to know if there's similar way to do it with local server files. Like
file_get_contents("./file.txt");
Please let me know if any possible way exists.

Comment: Have you actually tried doing just that?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (2nd example), you can use FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH:

```
// If strict types are enabled i.e. declare(strict_types=1);
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);

// Otherwise
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

The note says:

> The FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH constant can be used to trigger include path search. This is not possible if strict typing is enabled, since FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH is an int. Use TRUE instead.

And if you need help setting your include path: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: Thanks a lot for you time
I am using php get contents and put contents to upload file to server from url. I can also upload file from server or copy. What I have done it upload it to upload/ folder and name the file as time().rand(1,99) and characters after '.' at the end as extension. Now I can use url.com/file.img?rand.php and upload file with .php extension. Is there any possible way to do it with server file I tried ./index.php?rand.txt didn' work